# Programming with C# to install a msi

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a program that will install our msi packages for the hospital.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WindowsInstaller;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class InstallerTest
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             //Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
            //Installer installer = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            //installer.InstallProduct("C:\\Paragon_12.1.msi /qn     ADDLOCAL=DR,PI,MR,OM,PM,PV,RA,RM,RG,SR,ST,TR,AP,AS,GL,JS,PP,QM,UR,CC,ED,FA,LB,MM,MA,OR,PS,PR,RX,CR,RD,RS KEY_CC=blank KEY_ED=blank KEY_FA=blank KEY_LB=blank KEY_MA=blank KEY_MM=blank KEY_OR=blank KEY_PR=blank KEY_PS=blank KEY_RD=blank KEY_RS=blank KEY_RX=blank, @"C:\Paragon_12.1.msi");

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qn ADDLOCAL=DR,PI,MR,OM,PM,PV,RA,RM,RG,SR,ST,TR,AP,AS,GL,JS,PP,QM,UR,CC,ED,FA,LB,MM,MA,OR,PS,PR,RX,CR,RD,RS KEY_CC=blank KEY_ED=blank KEY_FA=blank KEY_LB=blank KEY_MA=blank KEY_MM=blank KEY_OR=blank KEY_PR=blank KEY_PS=blank KEY_RD=blank KEY_RS=blank KEY_RX=blank, @"C:\Paragon_12.1.msi");
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "Open";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

        }

    }
}
```

I've come up with this but when i run it, it only shows me the switches i can use, I want to to silently install this program and add the serial number too it. It works in a bat file.

Comment: Your string.Format has mismatched quotes

Comment: Your format string doesn't look good. Are you missing some quotes? And you never embed the parameter `{0}` in your string.

Comment: you need to look up how `string.Format` works where are the formatted Params that you are using.? you're missing things like this for example `"{0}" ect... and then the value to fill the params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qn ADDLOCAL=DR,PI,MR,OM,PM,PV,RA,RM,RG,SR,ST,TR,AP,AS,GL,JS,PP,QM,UR,CC,ED,FA,LB,MM,MA,OR,PS,PR,RX,CR,RD,RS KEY_CC=blank KEY_ED=blank KEY_FA=blank KEY_LB=blank KEY_MA=blank KEY_MM=blank KEY_OR=blank KEY_PR=blank KEY_PS=blank KEY_RD=blank KEY_RS=blank KEY_RX=blank, @"C:\Paragon_12.1.msi");
```

to

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/i \"{0}\" /qn ADDLOCAL=DR,PI,MR,OM,PM,PV,RA,RM,RG,SR,ST,TR,AP,AS,GL,JS,PP,QM,UR,CC,ED,FA,LB,MM,MA,OR,PS,PR,RX,CR,RD,RS KEY_CC=blank KEY_ED=blank KEY_FA=blank KEY_LB=blank KEY_MA=blank KEY_MM=blank KEY_OR=blank KEY_PR=blank KEY_PS=blank KEY_RD=blank KEY_RS=blank KEY_RX=blank", @"C:\Paragon_12.1.msi");
```

This will place the second parameter in your string, I double quote it in case you end up with a path that has a space in it. I also added the `/i` switch in front of it.

The `{0}` says to place the first argument at that loction. Example:

```
string result = String.Format("Hello {0}, how are you? My name is {1}.", "Jim", "Bob");
//result will be "Hello Jim, how are you? My name is Bob."
```